# Table Has No Column (code 1) Error Android

Tags: android, sql, database

I am trying to insert a new column in my database..by altering the database...and it works fine if there is previous data in the database...But if app is newly installed and trying to create first data then it is showing "Table has no such column error(code 1): 
Please Someone Help with the Solution:
**CODE:**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   private static final String LOG=DatabaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=2;
   public static final String DATABASE_NAME="NotesDB";
   public SQLiteDatabase database;

   public static final String TABLE_NOTES="notes";
   public static final String KEY_ID="id";
   public static final String KEY_TITLE="title";
   public static final String KEY_CONTENT="content";
   public static final String KEY_UPDATED_AT="updated_at";
   public static final String KEY_COLOR="color";

/*private static final String DATABASE_ALTER_COLOR = "ALTER TABLE "
        + TABLE_NOTES + " ADD COLUMN " + KEY_COLOR + " INT";

private static final String DATABASE_ALTER_COLOR_1 = "ALTER TABLE "
        + TABLE_NOTES + " ADD COLUMN " + KEY_COLOR + " INTEGER";*/

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_NOTE="CREATE TABLE "
        +TABLE_NOTES+"("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        +KEY_TITLE+" TEXT, "
        +KEY_CONTENT+" TEXT, "
        +KEY_UPDATED_AT+" BIGINT "+" )";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NOTE);
}

public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase, int paramInt1, int paramInt2) {
    onUpgrade(paramSQLiteDatabase, paramInt1, paramInt2);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(oldVersion < 2){
        //final String ALTER_TABLE = "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NOTES +
          //      " ADD COLUMN "+ KEY_COLOR+ " INT not null;";
        final String DATABASE_ALTER_COLOR = "ALTER TABLE "
                + TABLE_NOTES + " ADD COLUMN " + KEY_COLOR + " INTEGER";
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_ALTER_COLOR);
    }/*else {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + TABLE_NOTES);
        onCreate(db);
    }*/
}

public long createNote(Note note){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, note.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_CONTENT, note.getContent());
    values.put(KEY_UPDATED_AT, note.getUpdatedAt().getTime());
    values.put(KEY_COLOR,note.getColor());
    return db.insert(TABLE_NOTES, null, values);
}

public List<Note> getAllNotes(){
    List<Note> result=new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    String selectQuery="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NOTES;
    Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            Note note=new Note();
            note.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID)));
            note.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TITLE)));
            note.setContent(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CONTENT)));
            note.setUpdatedAt(new Date(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_UPDATED_AT))));
            note.setColor(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_COLOR)));
            result.add(note);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}

public void updateNote(Note note){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, note.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_CONTENT, note.getContent());
    values.put(KEY_UPDATED_AT, note.getUpdatedAt().getTime());
    values.put(KEY_COLOR,note.getColor());
    db.update(TABLE_NOTES, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(note.getId())});
}
```

LOG:

```
table notes has no column named color
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table notes has no column named color (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO notes(updated_at,title,content,color) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:891)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:502)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
 at com.revodroid.notes.notes.Adapter.DatabaseHelper.createNote(DatabaseHelper.java:81)
 at com.revodroid.notes.notes.Activity.MainActivity.addNote(MainActivity.java:855)
 at com.revodroid.notes.notes.Activity.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:846)
 at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6192)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3603)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3650)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1370)
```

How do I insert a column into table without losing previous data in database>???
Help is Very Highly Appreciated..!!!

Comment: Increase your DATABASE_VERSION constant value and remove the if condition in `onUpgrade()` .

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I have already increased the Database Version from 1 to 2 and I will try again by removing if condition!!

Comment: recheck your queries again that they are correct or not...

Comment: @FrankN.Stein It didn't worked!

Comment: @Sayem Verified Lot of Times..they are correct...but still it is saying no such column even after altering it..!! :(

Comment: Then: backup your data, uninstall and reinstall your app, restore the data.

Comment: Can you post your table **structure**?

Comment: @NigamPatro Everything about my database is in the code..!!

Comment: @FrankN.Stein If I Restore backup ...then it is working perfectly with no errors...But if the app is newly installed with no previous data..then it giving me error "Table has no such column" :(

Comment: No, because your app when reinstalled, will create the new column in the database. Then you reload the old data (only the data!) into the new structure. It depends on how you perform your backup. Using a CSV file for each table will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Check your "CREATE_TABLE" string. You didn't include KEY_COLOR in the actual 'create' query. You only defined it as a global variable.

Comment: I have provided it in onUpgrade() method with Alter Table KEY_COLOR..Do I have to also add it in CREATE_TABLE?

Comment: @PrasadShirvandkar yes you need to do that.

Comment: @NigamPatro if he's upgrading a production app with new fields for his database I'd highly recommend not just changing the create statement. Then it's more appropriate to use the `onUpgrade` method and use the alter statement.
@PrasadShirvandkar If this is just a new app, that hasn't been uploaded to Google Play Store yet, then by all means, just remove your current app and recreate the app. Just be sure that you actually remove the app or remove the data, because `onCreate` will only be called the first time you install the app.

Comment: @Darwind - he needs to do both - you need the `onUpgrade()` for current users, but needs to update the create statement for new users (who won't have any database to upgrade so `onUpgrade()` will never be called).

Comment: Now i am getting "Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it." Error ? Plz Help

Comment: Make sure you intialize cursor properly with "if (cursor!=null&&cursor.moveToFirst ();" before attempting to read from it